# How to make phone number clickable for desktops mobile phones only?

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, windows-phone-8

I am able to make the phone number only clickable on mobile phone by using the following:

```
var probablyPhone = ((/iphone|android|ie|blackberry|fennec/).test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
```

However, on the desktop version, your still able to click on the phone number but nothing happens which is fine. I would like to revert it back to normal

I would like to do the following but not sure how to add it:

```
function initialize() {
        (function($) {
            $('.call').css("text-decoration", "none");
            $('.call').css("color", "black");
            $('.call').css("cursor", "default");
        })(jQuery);
    }
```

Is it possible to do the following to add the function:

```
<strong>Phone:</strong> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i> <a href="{{" onclick="return probablyPhone" onload="initialize()">{{e.Phone | PhoneNumber}}</a></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you do that? Many users have Skype or some other phone app, on their desktop.

Comment: @lionscribe right....Okay what if the user does not have skype on their desktop? Also, how would I determine if the user has skype or other phone apps on their desktop?

Comment: You just put a phone link. Let the browser handle it.